# Convert Byte Data to image from XML Parsing

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

I want to convert this byte data to fetch an image from it.
i have used this base64Encoding method but this does not seem to be useful.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        NSString *base64StringEncoder = @"data:image/png;base64,";
    base64StringEncoder = [base64StringEncoder stringByAppendingString:[[parserDataContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] exhibitorByteImageObjectClass]];
    NSURL *profilePicURL = [NSURL URLWithString:base64StringEncoder];
    NSData *profilePicimageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:profilePicURL];

    if (profilePicimageData.length!=0) {
        cell.exhibitorImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:profilePicimageData];
    }

        return cell;

}
```

where parserDataContentArray is the mutable Array holding parsed Data.
and exhibitorByteImageObjectClass is the NSString property on which i am setting the node after checking particular tag exist.

XML Looks like

```
<PRODUCTION_B_IMAGE>
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKAAAACPCAYAAAB9NdDOAAAKQ2lDQ1BJQ0MgUHJvZmlsZQAASA2dlndUU1kTwO97L73QEkKREnoNTUoAkRJ6kV5FJSQBQgkYErBXRAVXFBVpig==
</PRODUCTION_B_IMAGE>
```

Comment: I can explain the code,if it is not understandable.

Answer (score 3):

Please download this : [NSData+Base64 files](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/NSData_Base64.zip)

dataWithContentsOfURL doen't actually take data from the URL but from the resource that is located at the URL. This is one of the easiest wrappers to use (decode and encode) base64 strings.

You have your NSString with base64 data in `[parserDataContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` I believe. So try this :

```
NSData *tempData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:[parserDataContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
if (tempData.length!=0) {
    cell.exhibitorImage.image = [UIImage tempData];
}
```

Comment: No known class method for selector 'dataFromBase64String:'

Comment: I did download what you have specified.Please tell me next process.Do i need to include it in my project and then use the above statements ??

Comment: Did you add the NSData+Base64.h and NSData+Base64.m to your project?
Did you include NSData+Base64.h in your current class.m?
Also make sure to add it as a target and to copy files to your project folder (tick the option).

Comment: OKAY !! you mean i have to include the downloaded folder in my project and then import what you have specified and just write the above statement ?? m i correct ??

Comment: Yes i did whatever you said.Initially it gave me an ARC error so i used -fno-objc-arc in compileSources and it went off.But it still gives me this error ..

Comment: -[dataModel dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x718b960
2013-07-17 14:42:39.074 xmlParsingDemo[9306:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[dataModel dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x718b960'

Comment: I'm sorry, add the entire project, it's been a long time since I've used this. Add the security framework.

Comment: I did add the entire folder and also added the security framework.Still it gives me one Error.

Comment: 'Security/cssm.h' file not found